# How to listen for events on postbin and get the values out of it?

Tags: c#, web-services, webhooks

I am testing out webhooks and I created a postbin test url and I am trying to create a webservice that would listen to the postbin url and be able to get the values out of the post, but I am not sure how to do this:  My sample postbin url could be http://www.postbin.org/abcdef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of anything other than scraping text.  Is this what you are asking about? If you want to scrap text, there are numerous libraries for any language.